# ActionMailer - Early return another mailer action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, return, actionmailer, mailer

I need to return early from `ActionMailer` method with another action to send other email if some condition is met.

```
class IssueNotificationMailer < Mailer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def send_notification(id)
    notification = Notification.find_by_id(id)
    return unless notification
    user, @issue = notification.user, notification.issue
    return unless user && user.active?
    return (render :nothing => true and deleted_issue(notification)) if @issue.nil?
    @url = issue_url(@issue)
    mail(to: user.mail, subject: "Issue #{@issue.subject} requires your attention.")
  end

  def deleted_issue(notification)
    user = notification.user
    @url = user_notifications_url(user)
    mail(to: user.mail, subject: "Issue which required your attention was deleted.")
  end
end
```

I wanted to prevent from sending `send_notification` email in line:

```
return (render :nothing => true and deleted_issue(notification)) if @issue.nil?
```

But it still wants to send that first email which raises

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should never put business logic in mailers. Why not invoke proper mailer in controller/model?

Comment: I'm using sidekiq + clockwork for email scheduling and it doesn't seem right to put this logic there either

Comment: Better than in mailer

Comment: The Mailer is not the right place for business logic. When you use Sidekiq than your Job object should do the check before actually calling the Mailer.

Comment: Gotta admit you fellows are right about the logic, anyway I was just curious if this kind of mailer-forwarding thing is possible